# Вывод количества изображений и даты вверху страницы с jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Этот код подсчитывает количество изображений на странице, но выводит в модальном окне, а нужно, чтобы результат записывался в какой-то тег, допустим p, и выводился вверху страницы. Также в этом теге нужно выводить дату в формате ДД.ММ.ГГГГ ЧЧ:ММ. Как сделать?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (){          
        var n=$('img').length;
         alert(n);         
        });
       </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+- как-то так :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var d = new Date,
      dformat = [addLeadZero(d.getDate()), 
                 addLeadZero(d.getMonth() + 1),
                 d.getFullYear()].join('.') +
          ' ' + [addLeadZero(d.getHours()), 
                 addLeadZero(d.getMinutes()), 
                 addLeadZero(d.getSeconds())].join(':');
    var n = $('img').length;
    $('#someP').html('Images count : ' + n + '<hr />' + dformat);
  }, 1000);
});

function addLeadZero(_val){
  if(_val < 10) return '0' + _val;
  return _val;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="someP"></p>
<img /><img /><img /><img /><img /><img /><img /><img /><img /><img /><img /><img /><img /><img /><img /><img /><img />
```

Comment: Отлично, а как сделать, чтобы день и месяц выводились в двузначном числе, например 07.08?

Comment: @BlackFire обновил ответ